# Python: How can I add sequence numbers to groups?

Tags: python, dataframe, numbers, sequence

How can I add sequence numbers to grouped numbers in a dataframe? Like so:

sequence numbers [image]

I tryed it with `df.groupby().cumcount()` but that didn't work

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

tmp = pd.DataFrame({'group Nr':[50,50,50,53,53,53,53,56,56,59,59,59]})
tmp['sequential Nr'] = tmp.groupby('group Nr').cumcount()
tmp.sort_values('group Nr')

print(tmp)
```

will give me:

```
    group Nr  sequential Nr
0         50           0
1         50           1
2         50           2
3         53           0
4         53           1
5         53           2
6         53           3
7         56           0
8         56           1
9         59           0
10        59           1
11        59           2
```

That is not exactly what i was looking for, as you can see.

Comment: you need to tell what you expect to get from the code.

Comment: I want a `sequence number` for each `group number`, which is ongoing.

Comment: you have a sequence of numbers. i see `[0,1,2]` then `[0,1,2,3]` and so forth.  so are you looking for a different sequence ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you just want to create a sequence number column, you can use ngroup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group Nr':[50,50,50,53,53,53,53,56,56,59,59,59]})
df["sequence Nr"] = df.groupby("group Nr").ngroup() + 1
```

ngroup numbers each group starting from 0, so you'll want to add 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can reach the target by the following code.

```
import pandas as pd

tmp = pd.DataFrame({'group Nr':[50,50,50,53,53,53,53,56,56,59,59,59]})
tmp = tmp.sort_values('group Nr')
s_df = tmp.groupby('group Nr').head(1)
s_df['sequential Nr'] = range(1, len(s_df)+1)
tmp = tmp.merge(s_df, on='group Nr', how='left')

print(tmp)
```